# Autocomplete magic in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.6

When I do next, I see all methods of sqlalchemy.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.func # <- autocomplete magic in PyCharm
```

How it works in PyCharm? By the way, pylint does not see it.

The following code does not work.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        _include_sqlalchemy(self, self.__class__)


db = Test()
db.func  # No suggestions :c
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because Pycharm isn't smart enough to realize `db` is an instance of `SQLAlchemy`.  (assuming `Test()` creates an instance of `SQLAlchemy`)

You can use type hints to help Pycharm identify what objects are in various levels of abstraction.

If you're using 3.6 you can add an inline hint (which I find the easiest).

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        _include_sqlalchemy(self, self.__class__)


db:SQLAlchemy = Test() # <-- add a type hint to let pycharm know what db is.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's all clear. I want to make my class and run my methods there. This is not related to SQLAlchemy. I noticed that PyCharm sees such hacks, and I want to learn how to do this for my code.

Comment: If you're not using 3.6, there are some in-line type hints you can use with comments too.

Comment: You did not understand me. I want an autocomplete for the generated code. flask_sqlalchemy it works, that's why I want to understand how.

Comment: Using type hints allows pycharm autocomplete to work on objects created in an abstraction layer. So if your `Test()` example is creating an object where autocomplete isn't working, adding the typehint to that variable makes it work.  -- [gist example](https://gist.github.com/bandophahita/b8b694210c958b51b701527511275a56)

Comment: [my example](https://repl.it/@MyGodIsHe/SpitefulHospitableProgramminglanguage) there is more clearly shown the class Test. I want to understand how this method works in flask_sqlalchemy and why my option does not work. In the same place, you see the Proxy class, this is my goal. It seems impossible, but who knows.